# Using nquad for a double integral

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

Having a problem here. Here's my code so far:

```
from scipy import integrate
import math
import numpy as np

a = 0.250
s02 = 214.0
a_s = 0.0163

def integrand(r, R, s02, a_s, a):
        return 2.0 * r * (r/a)**(-0.1) * (1.0 + (r**2/a**2))**(-2.45)\\
*(math.sqrt(r**2 - R**2))**(-1.0) * (a_s/(1 + (R-0.0283)**2/a_s**2 ))

def bounds_R(s02, a_s, a):
        return [0, np.inf]
def bounds_r(R, s02, a_s, a):
        return [R, np.inf]

result = integrate.nquad(integrand, [bounds_r(R, s02, a_s, a), bounds_R(s02, a_s, a)])
```

a, s02 and a_s are constants. I need to perform the first integral over r, and then the second integral over R. The problem I think is the fact that R appears in the limits for the first integral (something called an Abel transform). Tried a few things and every time getting an error that there are either too few arguments in the boundary functions or too little.

Please help!

Comment: I you need to calculate the Abel transform, you can just use one of the already implemented algorithms in https://github.com/PyAbel/PyAbel which will be more computationally efficient than using `quad`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write `integrate.nquad(integrand, [bounds_r(R, s02, a_s, a), bounds_R(s02, a_s, a)])`, python is expecting you to affect a value to `R`. But you didn't because integration is carried out over `R`.

This syntax should work :

```
result = integrate.nquad(integrand, [bounds_r, bounds_R], args=(s02,a_s,a))
```

Take a look to the second example in the [documentation of integrate.nquad](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html#scipy.integrate.nquad).

Comment: Thank you, this worked in the end, but there seems to be a problem when I actually want to pass a value to R for the second integral. So it works Ok if I put a numerical value for R in the definition of bounds, but I need to perform this integral in a loop for different values of R and I can't figure out a way to do it other than redefining my bounds every step in the loop.

Comment: which is of course solved by having this value as one of the arguments in the integrand. Thank you!

Comment: Yes you need to define an additionnal argument in your integrand and bounds functions to do that then add your iterating value in the third argument of nquad (args=...). Upvote my answer if it helped you ;)

Comment: It looks like I'm not yet advanced enough to upvote :(