# A question on double integration using SciPy's nquad

Tags: python, scipy, numeric

I am trying to get the following result using (numerical) double integration of the two partial derivatives:

```
def deriv_y(x,y):
    return -2*x*y*np.exp(-x**2-y**2)
```

and

```
def deriv_x(x,y):
    return (1-2*x**2)*np.exp(-x**2-y**2)
```

The function is an introductory example suitable for novices. The derivatives and some properties are provided [here by Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20x*e%5E%28-x%5E2-y%5E2%29).
This function is also used by [this tutorial "3D Surface Plots"](https://problemsolvingwithpython.com/06-Plotting-with-Matplotlib/06.16-3D-Surface-Plots/).

[image]

Successfully I could integrate the function along the x-Axis by implementing:

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

arr_x = np.arange(-5,5,0.5)
arr_y = np.arange(-5,5,0.5)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(arr_x, arr_y)
Z = np.zeros([arr_x.size, arr_y.size])

def deriv_y(x,y):
    return 2*x*y*np.exp(-x**2-y**2)
def deriv_x(x,y):
    return (1-2*x**2)*np.exp(-x**2-y**2)
def bounds_x(y):
        return [y, np.inf]
def bounds_y():
        return [0, np.inf]

for idx_x, x in enumerate(arr_x):
   for idx_y, y in enumerate(arr_y):
       m = integrate.nquad(deriv_x, [bounds_x(y), bounds_y])
       Z[idx_x][idx_y] = m[0]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
mycmap = plt.get_cmap('gist_earth')
surf1 = ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=mycmap)
fig.colorbar(surf1, ax=ax1, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```

The output seems to be correct:

[image]

I have read the [official documentation "Integration (scipy.integrate)"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html). Then I tried to chain both functions `deriv_x` and `deriv_y` in many combinations. In any case a got some wrong plots. I would be greateful if anyone could help me, doing it right.

Comment: To be clear, do you want the function to match the first picture / the graph outputs by Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: I want the second picture look like the first one. My problem is that I only integrated the function along one direction (x-direction). The Wolfram Alpha link serves as a helping reference for the function and its derivatives.

Comment: Oh I see now you want to integrate the partial derivatives to get the original function given in the tutorial right?

Comment: Yes - absolutely correct. I think I am missing one step. I dont know how to bring both directions together (x and y). Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: I've been playing around with different combination of the derivatives but I think the main thing is the bounds. This is the closest I've gotten so far: https://imgur.com/a/WWl6ljx 

May I ask how you are getting these bounds?

Comment: Your result looks almost similar to what we would like to get. I played with these bounds a bit and orientated myself to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35244855/using-nquad-for-a-double-integral](this post). But I am not sure if my bounds are correct. My hope is that we can use the infinity bounds describing the whole integral.

Comment: The strange thing is: Even a more simple integration example: [this star like surface](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28e%5E%28-x*y%29%29+dxdy) I couldn't make working. I am missing something fundamentally in the correct usage of SciPy.

Comment: To understand better the boundaries, I asked [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261441/how-do-i-integrate-and-plot-the-function-int-int-e-x-cdot-ydx-dy-numerical?noredirect=1#comment650953_261441). Now it is clear: boundaries are only allowed to go from `-np.inf` to `0`.